# Replacing the elements in array of arrays of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have this array:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1]]])
```

I want to replace the [1, 1, 1] arrays with [255, 255, 255] arrays. I tried using numpy.where, but it returns individual elements of arrays. I want to replace the whole [1, 1, 1] arrays. How would I do that?

**What I tried so far:**

1.

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        if blackwhite[i][j][0] == 1:
            if blackwhite[i][j][1] == 1:
                if blackwhite[i][j][2] = 1:
                    blackwhite[i][j][0] = 255
                    blackwhite[i][j][1] = 255
                    blackwhite[i][j][2] = 255
```

Did not work.

2. `b = np.where(blackwhite == [1, 1, 1])`
   This returns individual elements

**Update:**

The first method I tried is working but I imagine its slow for larger arrays. I have to work on an 8192 by 8192 array. Suggest a faster way?

Comment: Only the [1, 1, 1] arrays? Or anywhere there is a 1?

Comment: The whole [1, 1, 1] arrays

Comment: Can you report the expected output and what have you tried so far?

Comment: That is *not* an array of arrays. That is a `numpy.ndarray` which implement true multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: Anyway, I think you just want `arr[(arr == 1).all(axis=-1)] = [255, 255, 255]`

Comment: Thanks, yeah. Any advice on how I would go about becoming good at numpy arrays?

Comment: Also, I want to calculate the number of elements replaced when I do the .all command. How will I do that?